# Net use on scheduled bat

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I have this bat file scheduled in a windows server 2008 r2:

```
net use \\ip\share\employees\ /user:domain\user password
robocopy C:\Zucchetti\Timbrature\sicurezza\ \\ip\share\employees\ Timbrature_Giornaliere_5min.csv /R:0 /W:0 /v > C:\Zucchetti\Timbrature\sicurezza\logcopia.txt
del "Timbrature_Giornaliere_5min.csv"
```

If I run the bat manually the it runs fine.
If I run the bat scheduled with windows server 2008 task scheduler wether the user is logged on or not I get the following error in the log:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows                              
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Thu Mar 21 16:52:00 2019

2019/03/21 16:52:00 ERROR 1326 (0x0000052E) Getting File System Type of Destination \\ip\share\employees\
Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.

   Source : C:\Zucchetti\Timbrature\sicurezza\
     Dest - \\ip\share\employees\

    Files : Timbrature_Giornaliere_5min.csv

  Options : /V /COPY:DAT /R:0 /W:0 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

2019/03/21 16:52:00 ERROR 1326 (0x0000052E) Accessing Destination Directory \\ip\share\employees\
Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.
```

How could I make it work in a scheduled bat file?

Comment: I'm not sure why, but this solutions seems to work: log on as the user that run the schedule, open the credential manager, save the credentials for the network drive, log off. now the scheduler is working.

Comment: If you run the commands manually, it works fine. If you put the commands in a batchfile and have them scheduled, it fails. What if you put the commands in a batchfile and run that batchfile manually? (Or is this what you meant?)